# Node crypto HMAC returns <SlowBuffer> instead of String

Tags: node.js, cryptography, buffer, md5, hmac

I'm using the standard node `crypto` library to generate an HMAC MD5 hash.

When I try and read the hash value, the object that's returned is a `<SlowBuffer>` instead of an expected `String`.

Below is a simplified example, but it gives the same result:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('md5', 'KEY');

hmac.write('something');
hmac.end();

var hash = hmac.read();

console.log(hash);

//Outputs: <SlowBuffer 4c ec c5 6e 46 90 23 7a f1 2e 5a 78 35 21 6a 7a>
```

What is causing the hash type to be coerced into a `SlowBuffer` type? How can I avoid this coercion, or at the very least read the original value from the buffer?

If I set the encoding value of the hash via `hmac.setEncoding()` it simply encodes the value `<SlowBuffer 4c ec c5 6e 46 90 23 7a f1 2e 5a 78 35 21 6a 7a>` as a string in the given format. The same is true is I try and call `toString('encoding')` on the buffer itself.

Comment: Just tested and eg `console.log(hash.toString('base64'))` does work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the [crypto docs](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_digest_encoding) more carefully, it seems this is actually expected:

> If no encoding is provided, then a buffer is returned.

As the `digest()` method is deprecated in favour of `read()` I'd skipped over this and had assumed a default encoding would be used if none were specified.

The solution was simply `hmac.setEncoding('hex')`.